# How to create a generic array of flexible but static size and different type

Tags: generics, types, rust

I have a structure involving a statically sized array of generic data. In my specific application, it works fine, because I know what size is suitable for the context. However, I would like it to be more generic so I can move it into a separate crate that other people could use.

Specifically, my structure has (in the generic case) a type parameter `T` and a field of type `[(AtomicUsize, T); N]` for some fixed-at-compile-time N. The problem is that I'd prefer to not have to write a specific value of N into the class definition - the client code that actually uses the type should be able to define it as they want. I know that the language doesn't directly support generic integers, but is there any sensible/ergonomic way of doing this, or do I just have to pick a number?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no built-in solution for your problem, like you said, no generic integers yet.

You could tackle the problem using a vector with manually set size to avoid resizing and memory waste. But it still means heap allocations.

There is also a third-party solution: https://github.com/fizyk20/generic-array